# ALVR Client Mock application

Tags: oculusquest, steamvr

I am trying to build and run ALVR Client Mock application on Windows. As soon as I start the application, I am getting error. There is no proper documentation on how to test the Client Mock application.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to build and run ALVR's `v20.5` branch on Windows 11 with these commands:

```
# build
cargo build --bin alvr_client_mock

# run
cargo run --bin alvr_client_mock
```